# Jenkins Running shell scripts in reverse?

Tags: bash, jenkins, tomcat6, sh, jenkins-plugins

My jenkins server has a problem of running shell commands in reverse order.
I specify the commands to run

1. copy over a file to another server
2. run the update script

For example,

```
$nohup scp -i .ssh/blah -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no foo.txt tomcat@foo.coo.com:/tmp/FOO.txt &> /dev/null
$nohup ssh -t -t -n -i .ssh/blah -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no tomcat@foo.coo.com '/home/tomcat/bin/update.sh /tmp/FOO.txt.war'
```

instead the jenkins output console would show:

1. running update.sh
2. copying over the file

the same problem also occurs when i pair the two commands into one with &&
and it happens with all my jobs on jenkins

i'm currently running jenkins 1.469 on a tomcat6 server

any help would be appreciated thanks!

EDIT:

i'm running these commands as batch tasks for each job. the problem doesn't seem to be jenkins as this ran correctly

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/tomcat6-tomcat6-tmp/hudson8724999678434432030.sh
+ echo 1
1
+ echo 2
2
+ echo 3
3
+ echo 4
4
```

Comment: Have you tried saving both commands in a file, omitting the `nohup`, and invoking that script file?

Comment: the way my jenkins jobs are setup prevents me from moving the commands into a script file as they are all batch tasks.

however, i do know it will run correctly if execute from a single script. so the problem might not be jenkins itself

Comment: You are backgrounding the first task and immediately starting the next. If the time it takes to complete the first greater than the time to complete the second then of course the first command will finish earlier. If the order of these things really matters why don't you simply *not background* the first command?

Comment: none of the commands should be running in the background as &> /dev/null should be redirecting stderr to stout. or am i wrong?

Comment: i deleted the & and it worked! =X though i would still like to know why it was seen as a background job instead of a redirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `&>` to redirect both stdout and stderr is a feature of the bash shell. If you want to use bash-specific features, you need to let Jenkins know the build step should be executed using bash.

This can be done in two ways:

1) Change the default shell in Jenkins global configuration or

2) The first line of your build step must start with `#!/bin/bash ...`

Note that `/bin/sh` is not always a symlink to `/bin/bash`.

Comment: i wrongly assumed /bin/sh was symlinked to /bin/bash but it wasn't. so i created a symlink to bash and everything is back up and running. thanks!

Comment: Well, that's one way to solve the problem. You might have to keep re-solving it if an operating system update overwrites /bin/sh...

Comment: Also, note that by default, the -xe option is appended to the shell. If you want to preserve this behavior (-x echos each command before executing it - convenient! - ; -e fails the script if any command returns a non-zero status code - otherwise your shell step never fails! -), and if you use option #2, then use #!/bin/bash -xe